# Updating iOS Team Provisioning Profile in Member Center

Tags: ios, certificate, device, provisioning-profile, ios-provisioning

I had to register a device through Member Center instead of using Xcode, and I've read in the [App Distribution Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/DevelopingAppsThatRequireCertificatesandProvisioning/DevelopingAppsThatRequireCertificatesandProvisioning.html) that:

> Changes you make to your team assets using Member Center don’t automatically update the team provisioning profile.

I'm trying to find a way to update the certificates and devices in the iOS Team Provisioning Profile, but I don´t and Apple's docs only describes the process by using Xcode, how could I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As of Xcode 4.6.3 and the Dev Center rebuild, it is still only possible for these Xcode-managed profiles to be updated by Xcode.  Annoyingly, the only way to kick off that process is to connect the device and use the 'Add to Portal' button.

I have reason to believe the list of 'Connected Devices' originates from a database file living in `~/Library/Developer/Xcode/`, but I've not spent enough time with the file to determine how you could adjust it to list other devices such that you could have a 'Add to Portal' button to click!

I'd encourage you to file an enhancement request on bugreport.apple.com about it since it affects all of us now and then.